# Fala pra nós ou Fala pra gente?

Tags: pronomes, preposições, pronomes-oblíquos

Estão me dizendo que pedir pra um cliente "mandar pra nós" uma informação é gramaticalmente incorreto. ENTRETANTO, nós é um pronome oblíquo tônico que pode ser precedido por preposições. Então eu não entendo se eu estou mesmo errada e há uma exceção, ou se eu estou certa e o Controle de Qualidade tá mesmo pegando no meu pé de graça.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, "gente" é brasileirismo...Mas acho q o correto mesmo seria mandar-nos..

Comment: Acredito que não está errado dizer/escrever: "Fala (verbo) seu problema (objeto direto) para nós (objeto indireto)"

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, é linguagem informal, mas não está errado.

Comment: Tha, “fala para nós” não está errado e até entra na linguagem formal; “fala para a gente” ou “fala pra gente” estão corretos (vê https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1039), mas são informais.

Comment: O formal seria: fale-nos de sei-lá-o-que. E mande-nos, por gentileza, sei-lá-o-que. Esse modo de usar a palavra gente é linguagem inforrmal e falada. –mandar para nós, não pra.

Comment: @Peixoto, *a gente* não é brasileirismo; também se usa cá. A diferença é que neste caso, como eu o imagino, os portugueses não diriam *fala pra*, mas sim *diz a* ou talvez *conta a*: *diz à gente o que é que queres*, *conta à gente o que aconteceu*.

Comment: Não sou expert, para mim o correto seria `fala-nos`, `manda-nos`, `dize-nos` (ou `diga-nos`)... Mas, fala/manda/diz pra gente é correto também (nesse caso, talvez o erro dependa do contexto, fala, manda e diz são segunda pessoa, se tu usas você, teria que ser fale, mande...)

Answer (score 2):

"**Nós**" e "**a gente**" concorrem atualmente à posição de pronome da primeira pessoa do plural e são, muitas vezes, ambos usados pela mesma pessoa, no mesmo discurso, assim como o "vós" e o "vocês" nas poucas regiões em que ainda se faz uso do "vós". Ambas as formas são muito usadas no Brasil e também aqui em Portugal. Inclusive, em Lisboa, há quem use o "a gente" com a conjugação tradicional da segunda pessoa do plural, gerando frases como "a gente vamos à praia" ou "a gente vamos fazer".

Então ambas existem. A norma padrão da língua portuguesa, como é baseada em variantes mais antigas, não usa "a gente" gramaticalizado desta forma.

Agora, a questão da preposição: está correto, as preposições pedem pronomes oblíquos tônicos, como "mim","ti" e "nós". Talvez o que quisessem que fosse colocado era o clítico "nos".

> fale pra nós = nos fale/fale-nos

Tal forma também está correta!

Comment: Não acho que quem usa vós use o vós e o vocês misturados no mesmo discurso.

Comment: Há muita documentação portuguesa de pessoas que usam ambos, mas claro a grande maioria usa só "vocês" e uma parcela muito pequena usa só "vós".